# Understanding Deutsch Algorithm

Tags: quantum-gate, quantum-state, quantum-algorithms, hadamard, deutsch-jozsa-algorithm

From the image below, if we focus on the first qubit, we know after Hadamard (state 1) $|0\rangle$ will become $|+\rangle$ and the second qubit $|1\rangle$ will become $|-\rangle$.

What exactly would the result be after $U_f$? I understand that $U_f$ performs a CNOT gate on the qubits. But how is this result shown? By this I mean the image below is it (the equation for state 2), $|0\rangle$, $|1\rangle$, $|+\rangle$ or $|-\rangle$ and why is it that specific one? For instance, I presume state 2 would be $|-\rangle$? is it simply the process that if it was previously $|+\rangle$ then it just flips after going through CNOT gate to $|-\rangle$? In which state 3 then results in it being $|1\rangle$ ?
state 2:
[image: algorithm]

By states I refer to the bottom numbered symbols within this image below.
[image: state2]

Answer (score 1):

The $U_f$ is not necessarily a controlled-not (although that is one possible example). Instead, what $U_f$ does is, for any 2-qubit input in a basis state $|xy\rangle$, if evaluates
$$
U_f|xy\rangle=|x\rangle|y\oplus f(x)\rangle.
$$
The key trick here, of course, is that we're not supplying basis states, but superpositions. In particular, the second qubit is in the $|-\rangle$ state. Let's see the result of that:
$$
U_f|x\rangle|-\rangle=|x\rangle(|0\oplus f(x)\rangle-|1\oplus f(x)\rangle.
$$
$f(x)$ could either be 0 or 1, in which case the two outputs couple be either
\begin{align*}
f(x)=0:&|0\oplus 0\rangle-|1\oplus 0\rangle=|-\rangle \\
f(x)=1:&|0\oplus 1\rangle-|1\oplus 1\rangle=-|-\rangle \\
\end{align*}
This can be summarised as
$$
U_f|x\rangle|-\rangle=(-1)^{f(x)}|x\rangle|-\rangle.
$$
Thus, your output at $|\psi_2\rangle$ is
$$
((-1)^{f(0)}|0\rangle+(-1)^{f(1)}|1\rangle)|-\rangle/\sqrt{2}
$$
Now you can easily apply the Hadamard to the first qubit, and see that the answer depends on the value $(-1)^{f(0)+f(1)}$.

Comment: Ohh okay.. so state 2 would be |-> for qubit 2 and |+> for qubit 1 and state 3 would be in fact |1> for qubit 2 and |0> for qubit 1?  So for the first qubit being in the |+⟩ state, the result will be Uf|x⟩|+⟩=|x⟩(|0⊕f(x)⟩+|1⊕f(x)⟩. where f(x) could either be in 0 or 1 again, in which case the two outputs could be either 
f(x)=0:|0⊕0⟩+|1⊕0⟩ =+ OR
f(x)=1:|0⊕1⟩+|1⊕1⟩=+|+⟩